# material-ui : enable the dark mode automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

As per the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#user-preference):

It says dark mode theme will be generated automatically and get reflected in UI, but it is not working for me.

```
Dependencies:
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.16",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-alpha.15",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.16",
```

Code:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core";
import { green, purple } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import { useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import SignIn from "./ui/auth/SignIn.js";
import SignUp from "./ui/auth/SignUp.js";
import Welcome from "./ui/auth/Welcome.js";
import { log } from "./util/logger.js";

const App = () => {

  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  const theme = useMemo(
    () => {

      log(prefersDarkMode, "Dark Mode");

      const themeOptions = {
        palette: {
          type: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
          primary: purple,
          secondary: green
        },
      }

      log(JSON.stringify(themeOptions), "Theme Option")

      const theme = createMuiTheme(themeOptions);

      log(theme, "Theme");

      return theme;
    },
    [prefersDarkMode],
  );

  const history = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      history.push("/signin");
    }, 3000);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Welcome} exact />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      </Switch>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Signup.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import ForgotPassword from './ForgotPassword';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Copyright = () => {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
                Your Website
            </Link>
            {' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
        </Typography>
    );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        background: theme.palette.background.default
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

const SignIn = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const history = useHistory();

    // Forgot Password State
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    function openForgotPassword(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setOpen(true);
    }

    function onClose() {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    function goToSignUp(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.push('/signup');
    }

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                    <LockOutlinedIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="email"
                        label="Email Address"
                        name="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        autoFocus
                    />
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                    />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                    >
                        Sign In
                    </Button>
                    <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <Link href="#" onClick={openForgotPassword} variant="body2">
                                Forgot password?
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Link href="#" onClick={goToSignUp} variant="body2">
                                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </div>
            <Box mt={8}>
                <Copyright />
            </Box>
            <ForgotPassword open={open} onClose={onClose} />
        </Container>
    );
}

export default SignIn;
```

Background is not getting dark with the type. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. The latest version of Material UI now uses mode attribute of palette to determine whether dark mode or not. Simply change from 'type' to 'mode':

```
  // Enabling Dark Mode according to system-wide setting
  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  const theme = useMemo(
    () => createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        mode: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        primary: purple,
        secondary: green
      },
    }),
    [prefersDarkMode],
  );
```

Complete code of **App.js:**

```
import { createMuiTheme, CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, useMediaQuery } from "@material-ui/core";
import { green, purple } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import { useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import SignIn from "./ui/auth/SignIn.js";
import SignUp from "./ui/auth/SignUp.js";
import Welcome from "./ui/auth/Welcome.js";

const App = () => {

  // Enabling Dark Mode according to system-wide setting
  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  const theme = useMemo(
    () => createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        mode: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        primary: purple,
        secondary: green
      },
    }),
    [prefersDarkMode],
  );

  const history = useHistory()
  useEffect(() => {
    // After displaying Welcome screen for 3 seconds
    // go to SignIn page
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      history.push("/signin");
    }, 3000);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Welcome} exact />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      </Switch>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the newer version of Material UI, you need to use `createTheme` and not createMuiTheme

https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#user-preference

```
import React from 'react';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';

function App() {
  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  const theme = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          type: prefersDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
        },
      }),
    [prefersDarkMode],
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
      <Routes />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```